# Index out of bounds error even with .iloc in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

```
fraud_indices = np.array(dataset[dataset.Class == 1].index)
fraud_samples = dataset.iloc[fraud_indices, :]
```

I am using the above code on a dataset that has a column "Class" with 0s and 1s. What I am trying to do is simple, I am obtaining the indices in the dataset where the Class == 1 and I am using this to make a subset.

However I get the error "positional indexers are out-of-bounds" at the second line even though the indices are obtained from the same dataset. How can they be out of bounds? Can someone pls help out?

Comment: What about `dataset.loc[fraud_indices]` ?

Comment: .loc does not give an error but does not work correctly. I am supposed to get 492 rows but with .loc I get a random higher number of rows

Comment: hmmm, I check your question again and why dont use `fraud_samples = dataset[dataset.Class == 1]` ?

Comment: What's the purpose of indexing this way? Why not `dataset.loc[dataset.Class == 1, :]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) only:

```
fraud_samples = dataset[dataset.Class == 1]
```

and if need indices:

```
fraud_indices = fraud_samples.index
```

> However I get the error "positional indexers are out-of-bounds" at the second line even though the indices are obtained from the same dataset. How can they be out of bounds?

Reason is your indices are not default. So there are some values higher as length of `DataFrame` and function `iloc` selecting by positions, not by indices names like `loc`.

Sample:

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'Class':[0,1,0,1]}, index=[0,1,3,5])
print (dataset)
   Class
0      0
1      1
3      0
5      1

fraud_indices = np.array(dataset[dataset.Class == 1].index)
print (fraud_indices)
[1 5]
```

You cannot select 6.th row (python count from 0, so `5`), because does not exist with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
fraud_samples = dataset.iloc[fraud_indices, :]
print (fraud_samples)
```

> IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds

But if select by indices values by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
fraud_samples = dataset.loc[fraud_indices, :]
print (fraud_samples)
   Class
1      1
5      1
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using np.where( )

```
fraud_indices =np.where( dataset.Class == 1)
fraud_indices = list(fraud_indices[0])
```

Then, passing fraud_samples to loc index

```
fraud_samples = dataset.loc[fraud_indices, dataset.columns]
```